# How to tell docker to use a DNS server in an alternate port

Tags: docker, dns

Docker allows us to specify [some dns options](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services), for example the location of the DNS server:

```
docker run --dns 172.17.0.5 --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns-search service.consul --rm --name ping_test -it busybox
```

What if my dns server in `172.17.0.5` is using a port different to `53`? How can I dell docker about it?